# How do I extend the horizontal lines to be a bit longer as the one I have now is too short?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

```
\RequirePackage{amsmath,fix-cm}
\documentclass{svjour3}               
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
\usepackage{empheq,graphicx,mathtools,amsmath,amsfonts,unicode-math,array}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
        \caption{Results obtained using DTM and RK4 for $s(t)$}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{lll}
            \hline
                \textbf{$t$} & \textbf{$s(t)$ using DTM} & \textbf{$s(t)$ using RK4}  \\\hline
            $0.1$ & $17.60916776$    & $17.6091375512190$  \\  \hline
            $0.2$ & $14.91315356$  & $14.9104819873228$   \\ \hline 
            $0.3$ & $12.10171330$   & $12.0635013960239$   \\ \hline 
            $0.4$ & $9.560210755$ & $9.31079866900658$ \\
            \hline
            $0.5$ & $7.922673835$  &$6.88761960517152$  \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \label{susceptible}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), not not just a fragment. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

SVJour seems to be a springer class, which I didn't want to install. I simplified your MWE to this:

```
\documentclass{article}               
%\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[p]
        \caption{Results obtained using DTM and RK4 for $s(t)$}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{lllll}
            \midrule
           &     \textbf{$t$} & \textbf{$s(t)$ using DTM} & \textbf{$s(t)$ using RK4} & \\\midrule
           & $0.1$ & $17.60916776$    & $17.6091375512190$  & \\  \midrule
           & $0.2$ & $14.91315356$  & $14.9104819873228$   & \\ \midrule 
           & $0.3$ & $12.10171330$   & $12.0635013960239$   & \\ \midrule 
           & $0.4$ & $9.560210755$ & $9.31079866900658$ & \\
            \midrule
           & $0.5$ & $7.922673835$  &$6.88761960517152$  & \\
            \midrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \label{susceptible}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

I just added two empty columns to your tabular and I prefer `\midrule`from the booktabs package to `\hline`. Looks like this: 
[image: tabular]